# Does anyone understand HTML in outlook? I cannot get this disclaimer to show correctly

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have written some HTML to add as a disclaimer to company emails, which for the most part works a treat. I recently had to add some extras to it, by means of an overlayed image or 2. When compiling the HTML in web, it looks exactly as I want it to. However as soon as it is sent by email the images are blown up, one doesn't even show and the formatting is all wrong.

I think it must be to do with the type of HTML used by Microsoft when adding a disclaimer, but I don't know enough about it to know where I'm wrong.

Any assistance greatly appreciated!

````html
```
<tr>
<style>
    .parent {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image:url(https://www.douglas-scott.co.uk/storage/downloads/mwLPJ1KUs9YYEPTLfI3FaF84iaeXQjxDLvHcSLKh.png);
    background-size: 100% ;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 110;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.image2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;   
    height: 100;
    max-height: 100;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.image3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;   
    height: 100;
    max-height: 100;
    text-decoration: none;      
}
</style>
<td class="parent">
    <img class="image2" alt="SS22" src="https://www.douglas-scott.co.uk/storage/downloads/QRIe6dIZLotRovMPQosPFm1lqOBGeF5hPEZdFqJQ.png" align="left">
    <img class="image3" alt="£250 L2S Voucher" src="https://www.douglas-scott.co.uk/storage/downloads/l4BjlWxpIbGBzzBKQr12CiMl6zhMPAzU0sFd3NYI.png" align="right">
</td>
</tr>
```
````

This is my code, I only included the bit that isn't working. On web it is displayed as this: [correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdMqI.png). This is how I am intending for it to show.

However when sent as email, this is how it is outputting: [actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW2iT.png)

Comment: I would recommend embedding CSS styles as `style=".."` attribute rather than `<style>` tag. Not sure if that'll gonna fix the issue, but worth trying

Comment: @TheMisir thank you, I did initially have it as inline style='. . .' but it was still doing the same thing, I didn't know if it is because there are certain elemnts of style that aren't used in whatever version of HTML thats used for emails.

Comment: Yes I think there's client specific certain styling rules, limitations. I don't have much knowledge though. For example i think setting background image (with `<img>` tag) does not work on some clients. Instead you can try using a single image for the whole header.

Comment: When doing HTML emails you are very limited: check https://www.caniemail.com to see what mail programs support. use something like https://mjml.io to help with creating emails.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems here:

1. MS Outlook doesn't support absolute or relative positioning
2. MS Outlook doesn't support background images using CSS.
3. Images need height and width attributes.

Fortunately there are solutions for all.

---

Images don't self-size as they do on the web, so adding `height` and `width` attributes should solve that.

Regarding the layout, instead of using css positioning to lay out the images, they could be put into a basic two column `<table>`, like so:

```
<td class="parent" style="background-image:url(https://www.douglas-scott.co.uk/storage/downloads/mwLPJ1KUs9YYEPTLfI3FaF84iaeXQjxDLvHcSLKh.png); background-size: 100%;">
    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%; padding: 5px 10px; height: 110px; text-decoration: none;">
                <img alt="SS22" src="https://www.douglas-scott.co.uk/storage/downloads/QRIe6dIZLotRovMPQosPFm1lqOBGeF5hPEZdFqJQ.png" align="left" width="300" height="50">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 50%; padding: 10px; height: 110px; text-decoration: none; text-align: right;">
                <img alt="£250 L2S Voucher" src="https://www.douglas-scott.co.uk/storage/downloads/l4BjlWxpIbGBzzBKQr12CiMl6zhMPAzU0sFd3NYI.png" align="right" width="300" height="50">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

It might seem archaic, but this is the level of CSS that MS Outlook supports and it achieves the design linked in your question.

Regarding background images, we can use VML to simulate background CSS properties in a way that Outlook supports.

So we can wrap this code in a `<!--[if mso]>  <![endif]-->` so only Windows Outlook reads and renders it, and then repeat the background image styles in VML:

```
<td class="parent" style="background-image:url(https://www.douglas-scott.co.uk/storage/downloads/mwLPJ1KUs9YYEPTLfI3FaF84iaeXQjxDLvHcSLKh.png); background-size: 100%;">
    <!--[if mso]>
    <v:rect stroked="false" style="width:600px;height:1100px;">
        <v:fill type="frame" src="https://www.douglas-scott.co.uk/storage/downloads/mwLPJ1KUs9YYEPTLfI3FaF84iaeXQjxDLvHcSLKh.png" color="#000000" /> 
    <![endif]-->
    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%; padding: 5px 10px; height: 110px; text-decoration: none;">
                <img alt="SS22" src="https://www.douglas-scott.co.uk/storage/downloads/QRIe6dIZLotRovMPQosPFm1lqOBGeF5hPEZdFqJQ.png" align="left" width="300" height="50">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 50%; padding: 10px; height: 110px; text-decoration: none; text-align: right;">
                <img alt="£250 L2S Voucher" src="https://www.douglas-scott.co.uk/storage/downloads/l4BjlWxpIbGBzzBKQr12CiMl6zhMPAzU0sFd3NYI.png" align="right" width="300" height="50">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!--[if mso]>
    </v:rect>
    <![endif]-->
</td>
```

This should give you pretty good coverage in email clients, including Outlook.

I would also recommend inlining your CSS since not every email client supports the `<style>` tag.